# How to merge pythontutor.com with atom.io?

Tags: python, debugging, atom-editor

I am pretty new into programing and Atom...Though i have some gut feeling that pythontutor.com could be easily integrated to work with Atom, since Atom is built on web technologies and pythontutor.com allows embeding of both step by step and the live modes which are pretty awesome. I have this imagined like split screen in atom. As you write, the code updates on the pythontutor.

I tried doing this myself.. but when i looked into the coffee scripts and stuff it was just scary! I only know little bit of Python, and i'd like to continue lerning it with Atom :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After reading [some PythonTutor documentation](https://github.com/pgbovine/OnlinePythonTutor/blob/master/v3/docs/embedding-HOWTO.md) it seems that you can only embed static visualizations (i.e. you run your Python code once and it records the trace). I don't believe you can embed an *interactive* PythonTutor session.

If you want to stick with Atom, I might suggest the [`python-debugger`](https://atom.io/packages/python-debugger) package. It's not as learner-friendly as PythonTutor, but it's got some nice interactive debugging features.

Comment: I checked out that package, the turn off for me was that it doesn't have, watched variables or expressions. But thanks!